# MySQL Select Logic

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I'm working on an assignment right now and I can't wrap my head around the logic.

I have to populate an HTML select box with a list of courses based on a qualification code where the user is not already enrolled in a course.

Here is my current code:

```
//Get logged in users id
$currentID = getIDForUser($_SESSION['username']);
//Get logged in users qualification code
$qualificationCode = getUserQualification($currentID);

//Get and display list of avaliable courses for qualificationCode
$query = mysql_query("");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $courseName = $row['courseName'];
    $courseCode = $row['courseCode'];

    print("<option value='$courseCode'>$courseName</option>");
}
```

The layout of the database is as follows

Courses table:
[image]

Courseoccurrence table:
[image]

So, basically at this stage the combo box will populate with Multimedia & Design as well as Data Structures & Algorithms. However, if I select Multimedia and enroll in it, it will not populate the box with that course anymore.

Comment: what this line mean specially inrole in it? However if I select Multimedia and enrol in it, it will not populate the box with that course anymore.

Comment: So with the current data in the database (User hasn't enroled in either of the avaliable courses) the box will populate with both courses in it. However if the user decides to enrol in the multimedia & design course, the next time the list populates it will only show the data structures course in the box.

Comment: for that you need to check through a query that in which courses already user is enrolled and then extract them before showing.

Comment: If your not getting it in the dropdown then there is something wrong with your query, which you did not post.   Not sure why you would exclude the query on a mysql question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop using `mysql_*`, it's deprecated. Go with `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.
2. Not absolutely necessary, but you might want to change your collation from `latin1_swedish_ci` to `utf8_general_ci` or you will face problems if you ever decide to put special characters in your DB.
3. Now, to actually address your question:

   In your question you don't say what your problem is, specifically, but based on the title I assume that you know how to build everything except for the `SELECT` query.
   So, first you want to select all the courses that the current user is enrolled in. Then, based on the result, you want to fetch all courses that are not in the list you just selected.
   This can be done fairly easily with a subselect:

   ```
   // Assuming $mysqli is an OOP database handle
   $query = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT `courseName`, `courseCode` FROM `Courses` WHERE `courseCode` NOT IN (SELECT `courseCode` FROM `Courseoccurrence` WHERE `personID` = ?)');
   $query->bind_param('i', $currentID);
   $result = $query->get_result();
   while($row = $result->fetch_array())
   // ...
   ```

   **SQL Explanation:**

   I think `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE` and `NOT` require no explanation.
   `IN` checks whether a value is in a list like `'A' IN ('A', 'B', 'C')`.
   And `(SELECT ...)` is a so-called subselect (see [Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subqueries.html)), which is a simple `SELECT` whose result you can use in your query, and in case of it having only one column (because we only select `courseCode`), it can be used as an argument to `IN`.

Comment: I'd say the important bit is to not use an API that is going away eventually, because your code will then break. It is possible to write perfectly safe and working code without the use of prepared statements, but the same thing is not possible when your API is gone. But of course, one should always use prepared statements, I agree. Updated my answer accordingly.